# Setting the text appearance of an android TextView in Java code

Tags: android

How can I set the text appearance of an android `TextView` to large in Java code?  There is a method `setTextAppearance()`, but I don’t know how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try that:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

Comment: I’m new to stackoverflow, please explain me the **edit** page that was popping up

Comment: Well, I just edited your text to highlight some terms. It's a known pratice on SO to hightlight the terms related to the language you ask about, or just the code. In your case, I highlighted the code: `TextView` and `setTextAppearance`. You can choose to accept the edit or refuse, it's up to you :)

Comment: but i dont know how i did it, Sorry for bothering you,

Comment: No problem! But in fact I can't help you much, I never had to accept or refuse an edit... I guess there was a button or a link somewhere that you cliked on, maybe without noticing it?

Comment: What is the R in android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large? And can I add custom styles to this that I've creaded in styles.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```